# How can I better noise addition in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, noise

I'm trying to add a random noise from uniform distribution between min pixel
value and 0.1 times the maximum pixel value to each pixel for each channel of original image.

Here's my code so far:

**[in]:**

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Read image with cv2
image = cv2.imread('example_image.jpg' , 1)
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# Display image
imshow(image_rgb)
# R,G,B channel separation
R, G, B = cv2.split(image_rgb)
# Creating Noise

noise_R = np.random.uniform(R.min(),R.max()*0.1, R.size)
noise_R.shape = (256,256)
noise_G = np.random.uniform(B.min(),B.max()*0.1, G.size)
noise_G.shape = (256,256)
noise_B = np.random.uniform(G.min(), G.max()*0.1, B.size)
noise_B.shape = (256,256)

# Adding noise to each channel separately

R = R + noise_R
G = G + noise_G
B = B + noise_B
rgb_noise = R + G + B

noisy_image = image + rgb_noise
```

**[out]:**

```py
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (256,256,3) (256,256)
```

I'm getting an ValueError that the array shapes for rgb_noise and image are not equal. I've tried changing the shape of rgb_noise to that of image's but the I get a size error. How to fix it ? Is there any better method ?

Comment: Only you can decide if the output looks like you want.

Comment: While your target is the same, this is an entirely different question. You are now using a different library and you have removed input / output info. It is OK to *refine* your target, but changing it altogether should be keenly avoided. Please consider restoring the original question and asking a new question if you are not able to cope with the issue you have with this new code.

Comment: @norok2 I realized I will use the other code for my project and the code being here might be regarded as plagiarism so I did not want to take the risk. It's my fault really,definitely will not make the same mistake again !

Comment: If it is your code, there is no such thing as *self-plagiarim*. As far as the code from others in StackOverflow see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is a bit verbose, and could be made more compact.
However, the reason why you do not get *white-ish* noise is that you compute your red channel differently from the other two.

Changing this:

```
noise_R = np.random.uniform(R_min,R_max*0.3, image_G.size)
```

to this:

```
noise_R = np.random.uniform(R_min,R_max*0.1, image_R.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can be simplistic and add the noise by only the numpy array.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
```

Look, plotting the image will only work good with jupyter notebooks.
Do cv2.imshow() for other IDEs.

1) Have your Image

```
img = cv2.imread('path').astype(np.uint0)
```

2) Make a random noise

```
r, g, b = img.shape
noise = np.random.randint(0,255,r*g*b).reshape(r,g,b)
```

3) Blend them

```
image_with_noise = cv2.addWeighted(img,0.5,noise,0.5,0)
```

You can adjust the value of alpha and beta values.

There you have a noisy image!

Comment: Which part does create  random noise from uniform distribution between min pixel value and 0.1 times the maximum pixel value ?

Comment: @moli That is the second step... This was just an example, you can change the values bu your own... That lies between 0 to 255

Comment: @AAYUH SHAH in "addWeighted" part do you give half/half weights to image and the noise ? What does the "0" denote that is in addWeighted part

Comment: @moli The fifth parameter which I have given in the addweighted() is the Gamma parameter. The gamma essentially adjusts the Brightness of the image in simple terms. But in a technical way, brightness and gamma are a bit different. Here we only need the image with noise. Then, we don't need to have the gamma and there, it is 0. It is the compulsory parameter.